# How to connect to android service from a C client and inject Key events?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I am looking for a way to inject key/touch events to android input queue from a C application.
I checked the source code of "input" android app that can do this from command line. It is a Java app that binds to Window Service and invokes injectKeyEvent. But I like to do the same from native code.

I am not expecting this app to run on any android phone or tablet. This is for an android device we make where we have access to the android platform and cross compiler tool chains.

The "input" command implement this functionality in a method like below. I am looking for a way to do this from a native app.

```
private void sendKeyEvent(String event) 
{
        int eventCode = Integer.parseInt(event);
        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Log.i("SendKeyEvent", event);
        try {
            KeyEvent down = new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, eventCode, 0);
            KeyEvent up = new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, eventCode, 0);
            (IWindowManager.Stub
                .asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE,Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY)))
                .injectKeyEvent(down, true);
            (IWindowManager.Stub
                .asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE,Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY)))
                .injectKeyEvent(up, true);
        } 
        catch (RemoteException e) 
        {
            Log.i("Input", "DeadOjbectException");
        }
    }
```

Edits:
I have done some more research grepping android platform code.
I see an example where AudioFlinger is accessing MediaPlayer service from C++ code.

```
static void addBatteryData(uint32_t params) {
    sp binder =
        defaultServiceManager()->getService(String16("media.player"));
    sp service = interface_cast(binder);
    if (service.get() == NULL) {
        LOGW("Cannot connect to the MediaPlayerService for battery tracking");
        return;
    }

    service->addBatteryData(params);
}
```

The above code included IMediaPlayerService.h. I am looking for IWindowManager.h to get to WindowManager service, but I don't see it in android source tree.

Edits on 4/30/2013:
I see frameworks/base/cmds/service/*/Service.cpp that lets you invoke remote binder calls from C++. It wasn't clear how the test code came up with ids for binder calls etc.

I gave up on this approach. I wrapped my C lib with a platform signed Java service. I made lot of progress using Java api to bind to IWindowManager instead of native method I was pursuing.

Comment: So why don't you just invoke `input` from your native app?

Comment: Spawning a command for each key is not something I want to do.